# How to change image on webpage into the background image when onhover over the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a webpage and have six images on it I'm trying to make my background image change to an other image when I hover on one of my image and go back to my normal image when I out of hover.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or codepen with example code?

Comment: What have you got so far? Where do you get stuck? I mean, `onmouseover="document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+this.getAttribute('src')+')'"` isn't very hard to come up with...

Comment: i have try it first border and had set two of the same color but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to perform this.

** I just randomly take 2 images from some website.

```css
#test {
  background-image: url(http://www.cmf.be/images/button2.jpg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#test:hover {
  background-image: url(http://mygimptutorial.com/images/button-with-reflection/11.jpg);
  
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
</div>
```